# Disable landscape orientation for iOS 7 application?

Tags: ios, landscape-portrait

First time developer and have just setup the certificates to be able to run my application on an iOS device.

My application does not view nicely in landscape mode even with Autolayout setup. How can I disable the user from being able to view the app in landscape when they turn the device? i.e. its always portrait regardless of the orientation of the device? thanks

EDIT: Does Apple also advise against doing this during submission?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As Siavash said, the General Tab in your Target is the best place to limit the orientations for the entire device.
[image: Device orientations]

If you wanted to set all orientations possible but limit it for certain View Controllers, you could do something like this:

```
- (BOOL) shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO;
}

- (BOOL) shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
{
    return NO;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    if (condition)
    {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
    }else{
        return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
    }
}
```

To answer your second question, Apple does not critique an app based on its possible orientations. It's more up to you to decide which orientation(s) is/are best suited for your app. For iPhone Apps, users prefer Portrait usually for example (unless it's a game!).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer Natty! Just to confirm the above code should go into the viewDidLoad of each individual controller yes?

Comment: My pleasure! The above functions are to be independent. I believe they can be added anywhere in your .m to any View Controller which will - essentially - 'know what to do'. Give it a try!

Comment: @Nathaniel its not working for ipad in swift

Answer (score 8):

The easiest way is to go to your project file and under the Deployment info part, check the orientation that you want to have for each device.

Edit:
Here is the picture for your reference:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this (no code required) is to go into your app's info.plist file, look for an entry called "Supported interface orientations" (Key = "UISupportedInterfaceOrientations"), click on it's disclosure triangle to display the list of supported orientations, and delete both landscape orientations.

That will prevent your entire app from switching to landscape.

If you want some view controllers to support different orientations then the supportedInterfaceOrientations method (new in iOS 6) is the way to go. The other poster's code using shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation is for iOS 5.x and older.

Comment: I had the same problem and while the above answers didn't help me this one did. After all I figured out that there are two options in General tab (that above answers suggested - the iPhone and the iPad (with blue colour in @Nathaniel screenshots). So you could go either with your way or with the others just remind to check the checkboxes for iPhone AND for iPad